# How to use matchedGeometryEffect and view scaling

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to make animation when I tap on view it becomes full screen and when I drag down view it scales down and returns to its previous state. I use matchedGeometryEffect with two views and change destination view frame with DragGesture, transition to source view works «unexpectedly». How to fix it or how to make this animation correct? If I don't change destination view frame it works as I expect (click button). GIF here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXsjF.gif

```
struct Test4: View {
    
    @Namespace var animation
    
    @State private var show = false
    @State private var scale: CGFloat = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .topTrailing) {
            if show {
                ScrollView {
                    
                    Color.gray
                        .border(Color.black, width: 30)
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "animation", in: animation)
                        .frame(
                            width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * scale,
                            height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * scale)
                        .gesture(
                            DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                                .onChanged(onChanged)
                                .onEnded(onEnded)
                        )
                }
                 .ignoresSafeArea()
                
                Button("go back") {
                    withAnimation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 1)) {
                        self.show.toggle()
                    }
                }
            } else {
                VStack {
                    
                    Color.gray
                        .border(Color.black, width: 30)
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "animation", in: animation)
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            withAnimation {
                                self.scale = 1
                                show.toggle()
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func onChanged(value: DragGesture.Value) {
        withAnimation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 3)) {
            let currentScale = value.translation.height / UIScreen.main.bounds.height
            
            if currentScale <= 0 {
                return
            }
            
            let newScale = 1 - currentScale
            
            if newScale > 0.85 {
                self.scale = newScale
                
            } else if newScale < 0.85 {
                self.show = false
            }
        }
    }
    
    func onEnded(value: DragGesture.Value) {
        withAnimation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 3)) {
            
            if self.scale < 0.85 {
                self.show = false
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Test4_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Test4()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing that you are trying get is possible without matchedGeometryEffect, here is a simple approach:

---

[image]

---

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        ScaleView()
        
    }
}
```

---

```
struct ScaleView: View {
    
    @State private var translation: CGFloat = CGFloat()
    @State private var lastTranslation: CGFloat = CGFloat()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            
            Color.black
            
            ZStack {
                
                Color
                    .gray
                
                Image(systemName: "arrow.triangle.2.circlepath.circle")
                    .font(Font.largeTitle)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        
                        if lastTranslation == 400.0 {
                            
                            lastTranslation = 0.0
                            translation = lastTranslation
                        }
                        else {
                            
                            lastTranslation = 400.0
                            translation = lastTranslation
                        }
                    }
                
            }
            .position(x: geometry.size.width/2, y: geometry.size.height/2)
            .cornerRadius(30)
            .scaleEffect(1.0 - translation/(geometry.size.width > geometry.size.height ? geometry.size.width : geometry.size.height))
            .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0.0).onChanged(onChanged).onEnded(onEnded))
            
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.35))
        .statusBar(hidden: true)
        
    }
    
    func onChanged(value: DragGesture.Value) { translation = lastTranslation + value.translation.height }
    
    func onEnded(value: DragGesture.Value) {
        
        if value.translation.height > 0.0 {
            
            lastTranslation = 400.0
            translation = lastTranslation
        }
        else {
            
            lastTranslation = 0.0
            translation = lastTranslation
        }
        
    }
}
```